# The shell require user to input bquote argument post scp get command?

Tags: ssh, scp

While SCP ing from the secure linux server, the shell require arguments input to bquote> ;;
My inquiry is what is bquote utility with sftp? and also why the shell require another argument to cp to the destination. For context, first my user touched a file.txt to source dir before testing scp over WAN from destination shell. The goal is to know the argument types to bquote> ;; so I understand. Any resource will be appreciated

scp from the host source to remote destination, and destination terminal prompted bquote arguments for input

Answer (score 0):

bquote make out possibly stand for "back quote" and bquote may be prompted to null pointers. In scenario while prompted complete the pointer